# 'I eat kittens before ponies' vs 'I eat kittens before I eat ponies'

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, phrase-meaning

Are either of the following sentences grammatically incorrect? Assuming they are both correct, is one preferred over the other? If so, in what situations is each preferred?

1. I eat kittens before ponies.
2. I eat kittens before I eat ponies.

I have the same set of questions for the following sentences:

1. I put sprinkles on unicorns before lumberjacks.
2. I put sprinkles on unicorns before on lumberjacks.
3. I put sprinkles on unicorns before I put sprinkles on lumberjacks.

Comment: Seriously? Kittens before ponies, are they some sort of starter course? Do you eat their fur as well :) Are you writing a fairy tale by any chance?

Comment: The kitten sentences are all grammatical.  Unicorn sentence 2 is awkward, I might omit "on" in front of lumberjacks, and replace it with "the" (before *the* lumberjacks). Sentence 3 is grammatical but a bit redundant.

Comment: Note that "before X" can be understood as "in front of X," which can make interpreting the sense you intend more difficult—particularly in situations where, for example, "I put sprinkles on unicorns in front of lumberjacks" seems every bit as realistic as either "I put sprinkles on unicorns before I put sprinkles on lumberjacks" or "I put sprinkles on unicorns before lumberjacks put sprinkles on unicorns."

Comment: I hope these are all hypothetical:  I ***would*** eat kittens before ***I’d*** eat ponies.  I’***d*** put sprinkles on unicorns before lumberjacks.

Comment: @SvenYargs this is worth being an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Thank you, but my comment doesn't really answer the OP's question; it just complicates it further.

Comment: I actually like @SvenYargs comment and would accept is an answer, as it shows how #1 for both sentences is ambiguous, which would lead me to pick #2 for sentence 1 and #3 for sentence 2 (or completely reword the sentences).

Answer (score 2):

I believe "I eat kittens before ponies" implies "I eat kittens before I eat ponies." Both are grammatically correct.  If you want ponies to assume a more active role in the sentence, say "I eat kittens before ponies do."

Same thing for unicorns and lumberjacks, although #2 is a bit tragic. I think it might miraculously not be incorrect - but it's still awful, which is just as useless. They all mean the same thing. To make lumberjacks active, say "I put sprinkles on unicorns before lumberjacks do."

Comment: You've changed the meaning. "I eat kittens before ponies do" means I eat kittens before the ponies can eat them. (I can't believe I'm writing about kittens and unicorns)

Comment: Yeah, I was just saying that both versions in your example mean the same thing (and are both grammatically correct). Mine was an illustration of how you would have to change them to make their meaning different.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have "***before on***"; it makes for a double-take.

I think probably double prepositions have to be compound prepositions:

> "I lost 50p **down the back of** the sofa."
>   "He climbed **up under** the tarpaulin to hide.
>   *There's Fire Down Below*: sea shanty, with adverbs.

Except when you repeat the verb, when it unambiguously means first one, then the other, the sentence can mean "if given the choice, I would prefer."

> I vote green before UKIP. I vote UKIP before Respect,
>   I figure out  Sudoku before Codeword.

Grammatically these mean either I prefer the first; or I do one and then the other.

These ambiguities are in addition to those mentioned by @Misha_Rosnach

Comment: What defines a double-take? I can't seem to find a grammar-related definition of it. Is there another word for it? Wondering, because I believe "before on" might be one of those delightful word combinations that managed to fall through the cracks of grammar rules due to their sheer awkwardness.

Comment: @Misha Rosnach In cartoons, X walks by; and then swivels back to take a second look at something weird.  In psycho-linguistics eye-movements can show when a reader has to re-read a sentence after getting embroigled.  The words here are awkward because the brain thinks *'compound*  *preposition'* before it stops, reads again, reformulates the syntax, carries on.

Comment: Or triple; ante-pre-pen-ultimate.

Comment: Perhaps the brain might think that, but it *isn't* a compound preposition. I don't think anything *technically* forbids it from being there, other than the brain.